# how can I detect changes in document.hidden with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to run some code when `document.hidden` is changed from `false` to `true`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `visibilitychange` event. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange) for more information.

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  console.log(document.visibilityState);
  console.log(document.hidden);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [visibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange) event:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  console.log( document.visibilityState );
});
```